# Cakephp 3 make a search form

Tags: search-engine, cakephp-3.0

I'm a beginner in cakephp and I want to make a search form with "Search Box", "Select" and "Radio Buttons", I found some plugins, but I get lost when I try to implement it, I hope you can help me with some plug-ins and tutorials.

**Edit**

Form:

```html
            <div>
                     
<?= $this->Form->create($multimedia, array('controller' => 'multimedia', 'action' => 'search', 'type' => 'get')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('category_id', ['class' => 'electdown',
                                                               'label' => false,
                                                               'empty' => 'Categories',
                                                               'options' => $categories
                                                              ]); ?>
                    
<?= $this->Form->input('buscador', array('placeholder' => 'Search...', 'label' => false)); ?>
<?= $this->Form->submit('login_BDP_logo.png', array('type' => 'button', 'id' => 'buscar', 'div' => false)); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>

  </div>
```

MultimediaController:

```html
    public function search(){

$multimedia = array();


if (!empty($this->params['Multimedia'])) {

    $query = $this->params['query']['buscador'];
    $query = $this->params['query']['category_id'];

    $conditions = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'or' => array(
                'Multimedia.title LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Multimedia.description LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Multimedia.mime_type LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Multimedia.filename LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Multimedia.url LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Multimedia.language_id LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Multimedia.category_id LIKE' => "%category_id%",
                'Multimedia.created_by LIKE' => "%$query%"
            )
        )
    );

    $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->find('all', $conditions);
}

$this->set('negocios', $negocios);
debug($this->params);
        
}
```

**Update:**
This woks:

```
    public function search(){

    $multimedia = array();

    if (!empty($this->request->query)) {

        $query = $this->request->query['search'];
        $category_id = $this->request->query['category_id'];
        //$language_id = $this->request->query['language_id'];

        $conditions = array(

            'conditions' => array(            
            'and' => array()));

        if ($query) $conditions['conditions']['and']['Multimedia.title LIKE'] = "%$query%";
        if ($category_id) $conditions['conditions']['and']['Multimedia.category_id'] = $category_id ;
        //if ($language_id) $conditions['conditions']['and']['Multimedia.language_id'] = $language_id ;
            /*

                'Multimedia.title LIKE' => "%$query%",
            //    'Multimedia.description LIKE' => "%$query%",            
             //   'Multimedia.mime_type LIKE' => "%$query%",            
            //    'Multimedia.filename LIKE' => "%$query%",            
            //    'Multimedia.url LIKE' => "%$query%",            
            //    'Multimedia.language_id LIKE' => "%$query%",            
                'Multimedia.category_id' => $category_id      
            //    'Multimedia.created_by LIKE' => "%$query%"        
            )    
            )
        );            */

        $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->find('all', $conditions);

    $this->set('multimedia', $multimedia);

    $languages = $this->Multimedia->Languages->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $categories = $this->Multimedia->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $users = $this->Multimedia->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('multimedia', 'languages', 'categories', 'users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['multimedia']);

}
```

}

Comment: Cake provide form helper. you can use form helper to do this. 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: I already have the form, what I want is the search function

Comment: If you already have a form then in form action mention your controller method and hit query get data and render view.

Comment: and how can i do that?

Comment: Your code looks like cake 2 not cake 3